# Import a module in another directory python3

Tags: python-3.x, cmake

So I checked all other similar questions and this won't be a duplicate I believe.

I have this CMake library called [iris-distro](https://github.com/rdeits/iris-distro) that I want to be able to use anywhere in my system. it's basically a c++ library with python bindings (a Python interface). currently, after the build, I can only run programs inside build/install/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages.

I am trying to write a simple python code that uses the python interface from another directory and adding the following to the file.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'home/shehabeldin/iris-distro/build/install/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')
```

However, that doesn't seem to work and still gives me the error no module named irispy.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your path should have a `/` at the beginning. Otherwise it's a relative path that only exists when you're in `/`, which Python has no reason to be.

Comment: Sheesh. it's funny how silly mistakes can take time. thank you

Comment: You should not put absolute paths to your home directory in your Python code... very bad practice. You can instead add that path to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable if you need to use the package out of its build directory like that. Even better would be to create a virtual environment and install the package into that.